# lodash .get replace empty value

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

so i am using lodash `.get` to copy some array from my database to create a excel documents by using this

```
object[key.key] = _.get(item, key.key, '-');
```

where `key` is set of array and `key.key` is set of array column name or field name. it works fine replacing undefined value from database to `-` but there is also some fields that just have an empty value and i want to catch those fields and also changing it into `-`

how to do that?

Comment: What is an _"empty value"_? An empty string, `null`, ...?

Comment: empty string like ""

Comment: Thanks for asking the perfect question. I had this exact same problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If there won't be any other ["falsy" values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) the shortest way would be:

```
obj[key.key] = item[key.key] || '-';

// or with lodash
obj[key.key] = _.get(item, key.key, '-') || '-';
```

This will replace every "falsy" value with a single dash.

If this isn't possible:

```
const value = item[key.key];
obj[key.key] = (typeof value === 'undefined' || value === '') ? '-' : value;

// or with lodash
const value = _.get(item, key.key, '-');
obj[key.key] = value === '' ? '-' : value;
```

Comment: so helpful this!

Comment: FYI it does not replace `null` with default value which is again a `falsy` value.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
_.get(item, key.key, '-') != '' ? _.get(item, key.key, '-') : '-';
```